# Помогите Пожалуйста с решением задачи про сегменты

Tags: c++, алгоритм, математика

> Системные программисты фирмы Outtel работают над проблемой адресации памяти. Они разработали следующий формат логических адресов для компьютеров: <сегмент>:<смещение>, причем сегмент всегда имеет на 4 бита больше, чем смещение, но в написании логического адреса эти 4 бита не показываются, 4 бита сегмента всегда являются младшими и всегда равны 0. Пределы сегмента и смещение определяются, исходя из оперативной памяти компьютера, и могут быть для разных компьютеров различной разрядности. Так как <сегмент> и <смещение> в записи логического адреса имеют одинаковую разрядность, то физический адрес вычисляется по формуле: <физический адрес>=<сегмент>*16+<смещение>, т.е. разрядность сегмента увеличивается на 4 бита. Такой формат адресов позволяет сопоставить несколько логических адресов одному физическому. Требуется найти такой физический адрес, чтобы на него ссылалось как можно больше логических адресов, а также количество логических адресов, ссылающихся на данный физический адрес.
>
> Input Задается разрядность физического адреса - n (5<=n<=32).
>
> Output Требуется вывести физический адрес, которому соответствует наибольшее количество логических адресов в десятичной системе, и через пробел - количество логических адресов, ссылающихся на данный физический адрес. Если таких физических адресов несколько, то надо вывести самый младший.

Я не понял задачу. Можете объяснить её, пожалуйста.

Comment: У составителя этой задачи сильная ностальгия по ДОСу, поэтому условие этой задачи невозможно понять не зная о чём он там ностальгирует.  Адрес будет `FFFF0` (кол-во бит в F-части равно `n-4`), кол-во логических адресов = `10000`.  То есть, `(2^n)-16, (2^n)/16`

Comment: @ESkri к DOS это отношения не имеет, такой способ адресации определяется конструкцией процессора. И задача не такая простая, как кажется на первый взгляд.

Comment: Да, мой ответ неправильный.  Нужен адрес `0FFF0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сначала выразим физический адрес `P` через сегмент `S` и смещение `A` и определим границы:

```
P = S * 16 + A
Pmax = 2^n - 1
Smax = Pmax >> 4 = INT(Pmax / 16)
Amaxs = MIN(Pmax - S * 16, Smax)
```

Поскольку логические адреса должны адресовать всю память, то разрядность "физического" сегмента должна быть такая же, как и у физического адреса, а видимая разрядность (разрядность логического сегмента) на 4 бита меньше. У логического смещения разрядность такая же, как и у логического сегмента. Получается, что разрядность сегмента и смещения равна `n - 4` - это наиболее точная интерпретация условия задачи.

Начнём с `n = 5`. Физическое адресное пространство будет `0..1F`, разрядность сегмента и смещения `1`. Соответственно, будет два сегмента `0` и `1`:

```
Логические адреса      Физические адреса
0:0 - 0:1              00 - 01
1:0 - 0:1              10 - 11
```

Здесь мы видим, что никакому из физических адресов не соответствует более одного логического адреса. Ответ будет `0 1`. Более того, большинство физических адресов недоступны.

Рассмотрим `n = 8`. Физическое адресное пространство будет `0..FF`, разрядность сегмента и смещения `4`. Соответственно, будет 16 сегментов от `0` до `F`:

```
Логические адреса      Физические адреса
0:0 - 0:F              00 - 0F
1:0 - 0:F              10 - 1F
2:0 - 0:F              20 - 2F
3:0 - 0:F              30 - 3F
...
F:0 - 0:F              F0 - FF
```

Здесь тоже никакому из физических адресов не соответствует более одного логического адреса. Ответ будет `0 1`.

Рассмотрим `n = 9`. Физическое адресное пространство будет `0..1FF`, разрядность сегмента и смещения `5`. Соответственно, будет 32 сегмента от `0` до `1F`:

```
Логические адреса      Физические адреса
00:00 - 00:1F          000 - 01F
01:00 - 01:1F          010 - 02F
02:00 - 02:1F          020 - 03F
03:00 - 03:1F          030 - 04F
...
0F:00 - 0F:1F          0F0 - 10F
10:00 - 10:1F          100 - 11F
11:00 - 11:1F          110 - 12F
...
1E:00 - 1E:1F          1E0 - 1FF
1F:00 - 1F:0F          1F0 - 1FF
```

Из таблицы хорошо видно, что пересекаются не более 2 логичеких адресов, начиная с физического адреса 16 (`000 - 01F` П `010 - 02F` --> `010 - 01F`, 16 адресов). Ответ `16 2`.

Рассмотрим `n = 10`. Физическое адресное пространство будет `0..3FF`, разрядность сегмента и смещения `6`. Соответственно, будет 64 сегмента от `0` до `3F`:

```
Логические адреса      Физические адреса
00:00 - 00:3F          000 - 03F
01:00 - 01:3F          010 - 04F
02:00 - 02:3F          020 - 05F
03:00 - 03:3F          030 - 06F
04:00 - 04:4F          040 - 07F
...
```

Из таблицы видно, что больше всего логических адресов соответствует физическому диапазону `030 - 03F` - по 4 логических адреса каждому физическому (`000 - 03F` П `010 - 04F` П `020 - 05F` П `030 - 06F` --> `030 - 03F`, 16 адресов). Ответ `48 4`.

Уже можно определить закономерность.